# How to use PrimeNG's Dropdown correctly

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-dropdowns

I've followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55488741/how-to-use-primeng-dropdown) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53517301/primeng-6-dropdown-not-correctly-showed) question but their problem is slightly different from mine. In fact the first question doesn't even have proper answer. In spite of following everything correctly from the primeng documentation I am getting this error:

[image: screenshot]

And here is my code.

**app.module.ts**

```
//... 
import {DropdownModule} from 'primeng/dropdown';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ...,
    DropdownModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I've also installed `@angular/cdk` using command: `npm install @angular/cdk --save`

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3",
    ...
    "primeicons": "^2.0.0",
    "primeng": "^8.1.1",
    ...
  },
```

And my **app.component.html** is:

```
  <p-dropdown [options]="cities1" [(ngModel)]="selectedCity1"></p-dropdown>
```

and my **app.component.ts** is:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {SelectItem} from 'primeng/api';

interface City {
  name: string;
  code: string;
}

@Component({
  ...
})    
export class ContainerComponent implements OnInit {

  cities1: SelectItem[];
  selectedCity1: City;

  constructor() {
    this.cities1 = [
      {label:'Select City', value:null},
      {label:'New York', value:{id:1, name: 'New York', code: 'NY'}},
      {label:'Rome', value:{id:2, name: 'Rome', code: 'RM'}},
      ...
  ];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Please correct me.

PS: I found a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-dropdown?file=app%2Fapp.component.html) also. But unable to learn much from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a minimal [stackbitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1znydn) with a primeNg dropdown so you can see it in isolation.

You need to add css to the `angular.json` file and a some dependencies to the `package.json` file as per PrimeNg [Get started](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/setup) section.

That should set you in the right direction